# Program to repeatedly get the contents of a webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wish to get the contents of a web page that requires me to be logged in (and one that I do not have control over: e.g. Twitter or Facebook), for example I can have Chrome running and I can see Ajax updating the page updating, but I want to periodically get the contents of this page and somehow save it. I don't mind leaving a computer running to achieve this...

Comment: Depending of what you are wanting to store, you can use their public API's ...

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? Chances are you can use their API to get the information in a more efficient (legal) way.

Comment: all you have to do i smake a GET  request to the url and you have all the contents of the page just that easy.  If you want your client that you are making to also execute all of the pages javascript then you are in over your head and should just give up - meaning that massive projects are made to attempt to do the same thing and still struggle and based on your question you are not at that level

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use any http software to achieve this (like curl). Depending on the site it will take some investigation of how requests are made, in what order, the post data, the encryption, the user agent, cookies, headers, etc. etc.

It could take some time to find the right recipe.

Generally these sites don't want you to do this though, so don't be surprised when you run up against captcha or other clever methods from preventing exactly what you're trying to do.

Chances are, if you have to ask, you won't get in. But have fun.